# Tab key event not working when using key event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I am checking number on keypress using below function

```
function only_numeric(e)
    {
        var keynum;
        var keychar;
        var numcheck;
        if(window.event) // IE
        {
            keynum = e.keyCode;
        }
        else if(e.which) // netscape/Firefox/opera
        {
            keynum = e.which;
        }
        //condition for backspace(music) Key
        if(keynum != 8)
        {
            keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
            //numcheck = /\d/;
            numcheck = /[.0-9]/;
            return numcheck.test(keychar);
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

i called the above function in input box,

```
<input required="" onkeypress='return only_numeric(event,this.id)' type="text" name="test1" id="test1"  />


<input required="" onkeypress='return only_numeric(event,this.id)' type="text" name="test2" id="test2"  />
```

the validating number function is working fine. i need to use tabkey code(9) as like same like backspace keycode 8. if i use the code like below in `only_numeric` function

```
...

    if(keynum != 8 || keynum != 9)
                {

....
```

tab functionality is not working. What I done wrong here?.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`. `x != a || x != b` is always true when `a != b`.

Comment: `keynum` will never be `8` or `9` (though this varies in different browsers), `onkeypress` triggers the event only when hitting "printable keys". `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` detect also other keys, like `tab` or `backspace`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. I finally i got output, i modified my function like below,

```
function only_numeric(e)
    {
        var keynum;
        var keychar;
        var numcheck;
        if(window.event) // IE
        {
            keynum = e.keyCode;
        }
        else if(e.which) // netscape/Firefox/opera
        {
            keynum = e.which;
        }

         var tabkey = e.keyCode;

         if( keynum == 8 || tabkey == 9 || tabkey == 37 || tabkey == 39)
        {
                  return true;
        }        

        else
        {
             keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
            //numcheck = /\d/;
            numcheck = /[.0-9]/;
            return numcheck.test(keychar);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to revise your condition to escape <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>tab</kbd>. Use `&&` instead of `||`

```
if(keynum != 8 && keynum != 9)
```

Also I would simply reorder your condition like below,

```
    if(keynum == 8 || keynum == 9) /* and more keys to escape*/
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
        keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
        //numcheck = /\d/;
        numcheck = /[.0-9]/;
        return numcheck.test(keychar);
    }
```

Comment: For me keynum value for tabkey display as "undefined" always. but for backspace keynum value is 8. Is there any reason for tabkey value is undefined?